# onbackpressed in show file chooser

Tags: android, android-activity

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

}
```

hey. i used that code for pick image from storage. but if i press the back button in my gadget. he is fc . how to give condition on canceled pick from storage..and not force close?

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        if(filePath != null) {
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(this, data.getDataString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(filePath == null){
            startActivity(new Intent(this,HalamanUser.class));
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {

        Log.i("hello", "REQUEST cALL");
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("hello", "Exception" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,HalamanUser.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Is it an NPE on `data.getData()`?

Comment: yes the error is 'data.getData() is null'

Comment: if am press my back button in my phone he is force close

Answer (score 0):

When the user presses back, the result is [RESULT_CANCELED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_CANCELED), and the `data` that you receive is null. So the app crashes when you call `data.getData()`, as you are calling `getData()` on a null object. The are a few ways to get around this: you can check what the `resultCode` is, and make sure it's `RESULT_OK`. You can also simply check whether the `data` Intent is null before trying to get the data from it:

```
if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
    if (data != null) {
        filePath = data.getData(); 
    } else {
        // Note: if filePath is by default null, you don't need this else statement
        filePath = null; 
    }
    if (filePath != null) {
        ...
```